# Kibana Fails to Start after upgrading to 7.17

Tags: elasticsearch, filebeat, kibana-7, wazuh

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLfT2.png)

Kibana service not working after upgrading to new version. Try a lot of things but it's not working.
Firstly i did the all in one deployment of installing wazuh with elasticsearch , wazuh manager, wazuh server ,filebeat ,kibana.

All of this is installed in Ubuntu server with a gui .

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQuSg.png)

Don't take the kibana log.txt i added it later. Orginal file are kibana keysore yml and node options.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WfD3P.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edRa5.png)

Journalctl command

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCMMA.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqwHl.png)

I can't solve the problem plz help help help

(1) I did some troubleshooting with some command, check user , all the other service like elasticsearch , filebeat and wazuh manager all are working except kibana because when i did the upgrade for ubuntu sudo apt upgrade the kibana got update automatically . Since then kibana is not working.

(2) I except to solve this problem anyone please.

Comment: Can you check the logs you see when running `journalctl -u kibana.service` ?

Comment: kibana.service : Failed with result "exit-code".

Comment: Can you paste the last few lines into your question?

Comment: Hi please share your codes and results in plain text format not as an image